# Promise reject Possibly unhandled Error:

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, catch-block, hapi.js

I have a function that does some operation using an array. 
I would like to reject it when the array is empty.

As an example

```
myArrayFunction(){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
           var a = new Array();
           //some operation with a
           if(a.length > 0){
               resolve(a);
           }else{
               reject('Not found');
           }           
        };
}
```

When the reject operation happens I get the following error.
Possibly unhandled Error: Not found

However I have the following catch when the call to myArrayFunction() is made.

```
handlers.getArray = function (request, reply) {
    myArrayFunction().then(
        function (a) {
            reply(a);
        }).catch(reply(hapi.error.notFound('No array')));
};
```

What would be the correct way to reject the promise, catch the rejection and respond to the client?

Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

`.catch` takes a function as parameter however, you are passing it something else. When you don't pass a function to catch, it will silently just fail to do anything. Stupid but that's what ES6 promises do.

Because the `.catch` is not doing anything, the rejection becomes unhandled and is reported to you.

---

Fix is to pass a function to `.catch`:

```
handlers.getArray = function (request, reply) {
    myArrayFunction().then(function (a) {
        reply(a);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        reply(hapi.error.notFound('No array')));
    });
};
```

---

Because you are using a catch all, the error isn't necessarily a No array error. I suggest you do this instead:

```
function myArrayFunction() {
    // new Promise anti-pattern here but the answer is too long already...
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var a = new Array();
            //some operation with a
            if (a.length > 0) {
                resolve(a);
            } else {
                reject(hapi.error.notFound('No array'));
            }
        };
    }
}

function NotFoundError(e) {
    return e.statusCode === 404;
}

handlers.getArray = function (request, reply) {
    myArrayFunction().then(function (a) {
        reply(a);
    }).catch(NotFoundError, function(e) {
        reply(e);
    });
};
```

Which can be further shortened to:

```
handlers.getArray = function (request, reply) {
    myArrayFunction().then(reply).catch(NotFoundError, reply);
};
```

---

Also note the difference between:

```
// Calls the method catch, with the function reply as an argument
.catch(reply)
```

And

```
// Calls the function reply, then passes the result of calling reply
// to the method .catch, NOT what you wanted.
.catch(reply(...))
```

Comment: The fix was to pass a function to .catch as you suggested. 

The second option i.e. .catch(NotFoundError, reply); gives me the following error "A catch filter must be an error constructor or a filter function"

Comment: @juan did you implement NotFoundError

Comment: Yes, I it was implemented.

Comment: handlers.getArray = function (request, reply) {
    var name = request.query.tableId;
    model.getArray(name)
    .then(function (dataArray) {
        reply.file(dataArray[0]);
    })
    .catch(NotFoundError, function(e) {
        reply(e);
    });
  };
function NotFoundError(e) {
    return e.statusCode === 404;
}

Comment: @juan can `e` be null or undefined?

Comment: No, I return a message 'No array found'.

Comment: I have a similar problem however I am attaching a proper catch. I tried catch(error => {}) and catch(function(e){}) - the rejection inside the promise is failing all the time with unhandled promise rejection and the rest of the code inside the promise is executed - this is really bad...